# ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE

Tags: android-intent, android, start-activity, onactivityresult

My app is trying to install an APK.

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
installIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToApk)));
installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(installIntent, Constants.APP_INSTALL_REQUEST);
```

In my Activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.APP_INSTALL_REQUEST:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.e(TAG, "Package Installation Success");
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
                Log.e(TAG, "Package Installation Cancelled by USER");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong - INSTALLATION FAILED");
            }
```

When my startActivityResult is fired my activity instantly gets the result code 0 which corresponds to RESULT_CANCELLED while the System Install UI is still waiting for the user permission.

[image]

My activity to actually get to know whether the installation was successful or not and based on that update its UI.

Any help wud be appreciated.

Comment: Note that EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE is having no effect and can be removed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42253

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the culprit.

***installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);***

Though the system brings the existing instance of my activity back to life it is in the ***new TASK stack***. So the system cancels the activityForResult before it starts the new TASK.

Thank you

Comment: please accept your own answer, so that it goes off the list of "unanswered questions"

Comment: Cant do it until it is 2 days