# Exporting and installing apk from an apk

Tags: java, android, compilation

So, I've been looking for an answer for a while now and, haven't found anything, I resort to asking here. Maybe I don't know how to search this explicitly or how to ask the right question but I've seen many development Android Applications do it and I want to know how:

**How can I export and install an Android Application from another Android Application?**

I'm working on an app that lets you write and execute Forth programs on your phone and I would like to allow the user to export those applications as a standalone one but I don't know how. To top this, I don't even know how to search how to do this, so I'm out of ideas.

How can this be achieved?

I'm sorry for the frugality of my question, but I'm at a complete lack of words.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825636/action-install-package, or the f-droid project https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/fdroid/fdroid/installer/DefaultInstaller.java

Comment: Great, thank you! Would you also by any chance know how to set up a compile job from my app? I guess some os.system("g++ etc etc") is not going to work here...

Comment: Sorry, but no..

Comment: Had to check, you'd need to provide your ndk toolchain, but you can do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583487/hosting-an-executable-within-android-application